# RestTemplate & ResponseErrorHandler: Elegant means of handling errors given an indeterminate return object

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, resttemplate

Using a `RestTemplate`, I am querying a remote API to return an object either of expected type (if HTTP 2xx) or an APIError (if HTTP 4xx / 5xx).

Because the response object is indeterminate, I have implemented a custom `ResponseErrorHandler` and overridden `handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse)` in order to extract the APIError when it occurs. So far so good:

```
@Component
public class RemoteAPI {

    public UserOrders getUserOrders(User user) {
        addAuthorizationHeader(httpHeaders, user.getAccessToken());
        HttpEntity<TokenRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(HEADERS);
        return restTemplate.postForObject(CUSTOMER_ORDERS_URI, request, UserOrders.class);
    }

    private class APIResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
            try {
                APIError apiError = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), APIError.class);
            } catch ...
        }
    }

    private void refreshAccessToken(User user) {
        addAuthorizationHeader(httpHeaders, user.getAccessSecret());
        HttpEntity<TokenRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(HEADERS);
        user.setAccessToken(restTemplate.postForObject(TOKEN_REFRESH_URI, request, AccessToken.class));
    }
}
```

The challenge is that `getUserOrders()`, or a similar API call, will occasionally fail with a 'recoverable' error; for instance, the API access token may have expired. We should then make an API call to `refreshAccessToken()` before re-attempting `getUserOrders()`. Recoverable errors such as these should be hidden from the user until the same ones have occurred multiple times, at which point they are are deemed non-recoverable / critical.

Any errors which are 'critical' (e.g.: second failures, complete authentication failure, or transport layer failures) should be reported to the user as there is no automatic recovery available.

**What is the most elegant and robust way managing the error handling logic, bearing in mind that the type of object being returned is not known until runtime?**

***Option 1: Error object as a class variable with try / catch in each API call method:***

```
@Component
public class RemoteAPI {
    private APIError apiError;

    private class APIResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
            try {
                this.apiError = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), APIError.class);
            } catch ...
        }
    }

    public UserOrders getUserOrders(User user) {
        try {
            userOrders = restTemplate.postForObject(CUSTOMER_ORDERS_URI, request, UserOrders.class);
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            // Check this.apiError for type of error
            // Check how many times this API call has been attempted; compare against maximum
            // Try again, or report back as a failure
        }
        return userOrders;
    }
}
```

*Pros*: Clarity on which method originally made the call

*Cons*: Use of a class variable for a transient value. Lots of boilerplate code for each method that calls the API. Error handling logic spread around multiple methods.

***Option 2: User object as a class variable / Error management logic in the ResponseErrorHandler***

```
@Component
public class RemoteAPI {
    private User user;

    private class APIResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
            try {
            APIError apiError = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), APIError.class);
            // Check this.apiError for type of error
            // Check how many times this API call has been attempted; compare against maximum
            // Try again...
            getUserOrders();            
            ...or report back as a failure
        } catch ...
    }
}
```

*Pros*: Error management logic is in one place.

*Cons*: User object must now be a class variable and handled gracefully, because the User object cannot otherwise be accessible within the ResponseErrorHandler and so cannot pass it to `getUserOrders(User)` as before. Need to keep track of how many times each method has been called.

***Option 3: Error management logic outside of the RemoteAPI class***

*Pros*: Separates error handling from business logic

*Cons*: API logic is now in another class

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question: it turns out that there were fallacies in the question itself.

I was implementing a `ResponseErrorHandler` because I thought I needed it to parse the response even when that response was returned with a HTTP error code. In fact, that isn't the case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36227531/3474282) demonstrates that the response can be parsed into an object by catching a `HttpStatusCodeException` and otherwise using a standard `RestTemplate`. That negates the need for a custom `ResponseErrorHandler` and therefore the need to return an object of ambiguous type. The method that is handed the error can catch the `HttpStatusCodeException`, try to refresh the access token, and then call itself again via recursion. A counter is required to prevent endless recursion but that can be passed through rather than being a class variable.

The downside is that it still requires error management logic spread around the class, along with plenty of boilerplate code, but it's a lot tidier than the other options.

```
public UserOrders getUserOrders(User user, Integer methodCallCount) {
    methodCallCount++;
    UserOrders userOrders;
    try {
        userOrders = restTemplate.postForObject(USER_ORDERS_URI, request, UserOrders.class);
    } catch (RestClientException ex) {
        APIError apiError = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), APIError.class);
        if (methodCallCount < MAX_METHOD_CALLS) {
            if (apiError.isType(ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED)) {
                refreshVendorAccessTokenInfo(user);
                userOrders = getUserOrders(user, methodCallCount);
            }
        }
    }
    return userOrders;
}
```